# how to use the struct of parent class in son class

Tags: c++

After inheritance, the construction destructor of a subclass can call the structure type of the parent class, but other function interfaces cannot

```
class MyOther:public MyObj
{
    Node node;
public:
    void show();
    MyOther();
    ~MyOther();
};


#include "MyOther.h"

void MyObj::show()
{
    
    node.pnext=//there is an error,with red line,Prompt no identifier defined
}

MyOther::MyOther()
{
    node.NodeCh = 'a';
    node.pnext = nullptr;
}


MyOther::~MyOther()
{
    
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be MyOther::show() ? node is in MyOther not MyObj

Comment: There is no reason the parent object (`MyObj`) should know anything about additional members in the derived object (`MyOther`). Hence the error. The derived object, on the other hand, knows everything about the parent you haven’t explicitly forbidden with `private` access. (Note that `Node node` is in the private section of `MyOther`, so even classes derived from `MyOther` cannot access it.)